# Put the Money where your Mouth is

Tags: wordplay, word-property

Here's a addictive and frustrating puzzle that will likely make you tear your hair out. Even I do not yet have a perfect solution, but due to the endless possibilities of the english language, I'm sure it can be done.

Suppose we assign a value (in U.S. cents) to each letter of the alphabet. $A$ is worth $1$¢, $B$ is worth $2$¢, and so on, and $Z$ is worth $26$¢.
Let the value of a word or phrase be equal to the sum of the values of its letters. For example, DOG is worth $26$¢, and CAT is only worth $24$¢.

Can you find a phrase that expresses (in English) the same amount of money as it is worth (using the cent values assigned to its letters)?

Here are some near misses that I've come up with:

(off by $4$¢)

> ONE DOLLAR $\to$ $96$¢

(off by $3$¢)

> DOLLAR BILL $\to$ $97$¢

(off by $2$¢):

> THREE DOLLAR BILLS AND TEN PENNIES $\to$ $312$¢

(off by $2$¢):

> THREE DOLLAR BILLS AND ONE PENNY $\to$ $299$¢

(off by $2$¢):

> THREE DOLLAR BILLS AND NO PENNIES $\to$ $302$¢

For an extra challenge, one you have found a correct answer, try finding an answer that is worth less money.

Edit: I need to add some more rules to prevent answers that are too easy to formulate. 
In an answer, if more than one different units of currency are being used, the unit must be specified before it is listed in the answer. For example, BUCK ADD TWO would be interpreted as three dollars instead of a dollar and two cents, whereas BUCK ADD TWO CENTS would be interpreted as the latter.

Comment: Can we use slang terms for dollars and things (e.g. 'a buck')

Comment: Yes you can. I'm making it pretty flexible, because it's still really hard.

Comment: It is pretty hard. Closest I have is 'SINGLE BILL' which is 101

Comment: Wow... that's pretty close. Also, another idea, which I have yet to try, is to use the currencies of other countries (Euros, Pesos) to get within a fraction of a dollar of a correct answer (due to currency conversions).

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea as they are constantly changing

Comment: There are going to be many possible answers - to have the question have a single best answer you should have some way of deciding what "best" is, or this will be closed as **too broad**.

Comment: May I suggest an option for the 'best' answer: The smallest amount possible

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll add that to my question. However, it would also be an interesting challenge to find the largest possible... it's likely that there is no single largest amount, but it would be interesting to see how large peoples' answers would get.

Comment: Trying to find the largest possible would make this too broad. I could do 'A DOLLAR ADD A DOLLAR ADD A DOLLAR ....' to get infinity

Comment: Yes, but it would not actually be accurate at any of the steps. If not, it would not work (since nobody can *actually* type that out infinitely many times).

Comment: You might consider adding a criterion that the answer be a way people would actually express a monetary amount in real life usage. Otherwise the you invite completely open-ended answers like "dollar add a dollar add a ..."

Comment: Okay, I'm going to add some more rules to make this a little more rigid.

Comment: Following the rules change, some of the originally posted phrases are no longer valid solutions - you may want to review the answer posts and indicate which phrases are now ruled out.  In any case I think my current answer provides permissible phrases that are lower valued than any in the currently ✔Accepted answer, so that probably warrants another look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found three:

The current winning one (based on smallest amount) is:

> BILL ADD TWO = $102$
> 35+ 9 + 58
> 44+58
> =**102**

A very close smaller one:

> A BUCK ADD THREE = 103
> 1 + 37 + 9 + 56
> 47+56
> =**103**

And a bigger one

> THREE DOLLAR BILLS ADD FIVE PENNIES = $305$

So you don't have to check:

> 20+8+18+5+5 4+15+12+12+1+18 2+9+12+12+19 1+4+4 6+9+22+5 16+5+14+14+9+5+19
> 56 + 62 + 54 + 9 + 42 + 82
> 118 + 63 + 124
> 181+124
> = **305**

Rubio also found

> THREE DOLLARS AND FIFTY SIX PENNIES

Couple of close shaves:

Off by one cent:

> SINGLE BILL = 101
> BUCK ADD THREE = 102

Off by two cents:

> BUCK ADD TWO = 104
> BUCK ADD FOUR = 106
> BUCK ADD ELEVEN = 109
> BUCK ADD DOZEN = 110

Off by three cents:

> SINGLE BUCK = 103

Comment: Not that I'm biased (ok I'm totally biased ...) but people don't say "bill add two" or "three dollars add five pennies". My solutions are ways people might actually express monetary amounts in real usage. Maybe that should be a criterion of the question?

Comment: @Rubio perhaps. I've gone with their first comment where we can use slang and that they've made it flexible.

Comment: Some near misses:

THREE HUNDRED SIXTY ONE US CENTS = 362, 

THREE HUNDRED AND EIGHTY-SEVEN US CENTS = 389, 

TWO POUNDS AND TUPPENCE = 266 ~~ 204p at time of writing. This one could be true in the future if GBP rises. 

THIRTY SEVEN POINT OH FIVE HONG KONG DOLLARS = 476 ~~ 37.0578 HKD at time of writing. (The smallest legal tender HKD denomination is 0.1 HKD, so this really wouldn't be valid at all.)

Answer (score 6):

Here are my solutions so far --

#### 95 <sup><sup>1,2</sup></sup>

> Half a dime off **[ace](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ace)**.<sup>*sense 6*</sup>
>  $= 27 + 1 + 31 + 27 + 9 = 95$

#### 100 <sup><sup>1,2</sup></sup>

> A half ace, doubled.
>  $= 1 + 27 + 9 + 63 = 100$

#### 156 <sup><sup>3</sup></sup>

> A buck fifty-six.
>  $= 1 + 37 + 66 + 52 = 156$

#### 356 <sup><sup>1,3</sup></sup>

> Three dollars and fifty-six pennies.
>  $= 56 + 81 + 19 + 66 + 52 + 82 = 356$

<sup>1</sup> *Appears to qualify under current rules*
<sup>2</sup> *Definitely not something people would actually say*
<sup>3</sup> *Something people might actually say*

Comment: Huzzah indeed! Nice find!

Comment: You momentarily beat me, now I have 'BUCK ADD TWO' = 102. Sorry :P

Answer (score 2):

Made this small program: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPqzJa to help calculating the letters (just type your phrase in the box and it will show the sum), but it's still quite tricky to find a good match.

I only found one so far:

> three dollars and sixty six cents = 366